# Google GCP Storage Bucket Location change

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, storage, bucket

Can the location type be changed once the bucket is created? If true
If the location type is changed from regional to multi-regional, does the availability of existing objects in the bucket change? Or does this apply to only new objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In GCP, [a bucket's location can only be edited upon creation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/moving-buckets#:%7E:text=When%20you%20create%20a%20bucket%2C%20you%20permanently%20define%20its%20name%2C%20its%20geographic%20location%2C%20and%20the%20project%20it%20is%20part%20of.). I've actually got a feature request open to modify this, feel free to star it if it affects you:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/209361096